# Run pipe for each item in bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, pipe

Say I have an array:

```
ITEMS=(
  "foo"
  "bar"
  "baz"
)
```

I want to run the following command:

```
cat template \
  | my_command $ITEMS[1] \
  | my_command $ITEMS[2] \
  | my_command $ITEMS[3] \
  > output
```

I don't want to hard code the `my_command` for each array item, as the array is dynamic.

I can do the following:

```
cat template > output
for var in "${ITEMS[@]}"; do
  cat output | my_template $var > output
done
```

But this seems clumsy as it writes to the file multiple times.

Is there a way of getting all the `my_command` invocations into the same command, when there is an unknown number of invocations?

Comment: Does `my_command` only accept one input parameter? Or could you rewrite `my_command` to accept multiple values?

Comment: `my_command` is an external program which I didn't write, so let's say it has to be in the format provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use some good old-fashioned recursion.

- If there's only one argument (the `1)` case) run the command directly.
- If there's more than one (the `*)` case) run it with the first argument (`${args[0]}`) and pipe that to a recursive invocation of `multipipe` with the first argument removed (`${args[@]:1}`).

```sh
multipipe() {
    local cmd=$1
    local args=("${@:2}")

    case ${#args[@]} in
        0) ;;
        1) "$cmd" "${args[0]}";;
        *) "$cmd" "${args[0]}" | multipipe "$cmd" "${args[@]:1}";;
    esac
}

multipipe my_command "${ITEMS[@]}" <template >output
```

Comment: This is the clearest solution and doesn't depend on `eval`. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `printf` and the much maligned `eval`:

```
eval $(printf 'cat template '; printf '| my_command "%s" ' "${ITEMS[@]}") > output
```

Use it only when you are sure that there is no malicious entry in `ITEMS` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the whole loop block to the output, so:

```
for var in "${ITEMS[@]}"; do
  my_template "${var}" <template
done >output
```

Alternatively if your `my_template` program can accept multiple items as arguments, you can pass it all the array on a single call with:

```
my_template "${ITEMS[@]}" <template
```

This will call:

```
my_template "foo" "bar" "baz" <template
```

Comment: I like the first approach, and I think it will work in my case, but would it work if (hypothetically) each invocation of `my_command` depended on the previous output?

Comment: No, each invocation processes `template` independent from the others.

Comment: @FelaMaslen you could probably chain input and output in the loop by using a named pipe: `mypipe=$(mktemp -u);
mkfifo -m 600 "${mypipe}"; for var in "${ITEMS[@]}"; do my_template "${var}" <"${mypipe}" >>"${mypipe}"; done; cat "${mypipe}" >output; rm "${mypipe}"`